# Read Spring boot Properties in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, properties

**Problem Statement:**
There is one microservice of Spring Boot and Angular 8. 
Spring boot having one properties file(application.yaml) as below:

```
url-header: http    
gateway:
   host: envHost:envPort

ui-endpoints:
  get-config-by-id: ${url-header}://${gateway.host}/api/v1/config/id
  save-config: ${url-header}://${gateway.host}/api/v1/config
```

We are fetching these UI endpoints by doing rest call on page load in the angular code.

**Is there a better way to define endpoints directly in the angular ts file or can we just sync spring boot properties in angular without doing rest call?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environment.ts (local) or environment.prod.ts (Production) to define endpoints directly in the angular ts file

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but if I had asked the question I would have been ignored, or someone would have voted to close the question without commenting.

Here's what I did.

First, you need to add the following to your Angular application's index.html file:

```html
<script src="appprops.js"></script>
```

Next, you are going to need to create a Spring MVC endpoint.

```java
@RestController
public class AppPropsController {

    // or autowire via constructor, doesn't matter
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @GetMapping("appprops.js")
    public ResponseEntity<?> props() {

        Map<String, String> mapResult = new HashMap<>();
        mapResult.put("spring.prop.whatever", env.getProperty("spring.prop.whatever");

        String jsBody = String.format("window.props = %s", objectMapper.writeValueAsString(mapResult);

        ResponseEntity<?> result = ResponseEntity.ok()
            // gotta do this manually, the Spring MediaType doesn't have an entry for APPLICATION_JAVASCRIPT
            .header("Content-Type","application/javascript")
            .body(jsBody);

        return result;


    }

}
```

Now, referencing this on the Angular side looks like this:

```js
   // gotta use this weird index signature, window['props'] doesn't work
   const props : any = (window as { [key: string]: any})['props'];
```

It's convoluted and I hate it, but it seems to work.